Show that $\sup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n= \sup_{n \geq 1}\sup A_n$
Let $A_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}, \forall n \geq 1$. If $A= \bigcup_{n=1}^m A_n$, then we know that $\sup A = \max_{1 \leq n \leq m}\sup A_n$.
How about the infinite case, would be true that:

$\sup A = \sup_{n \geq 1}\sup A_n$, if $A= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$?


What do you mean by supremum of a sequence of sets?

@Mark, due to lack of attention, I wrote my question wrong. I already corrected

Do you perhaps intend that $A_n \subset \mathbb{R},$ so the supremum is the least upper bound, i.e., $\sup {x : x \in A}$ et c?

If you allow the supremum to be $\infty$ then the statement will be true even for uncountable unions. Try to prove this using the definitions.

One approach is to show the upper and lower bounds on $\sup A$ separately. For the upper bound, a hint is to notice that $x \in A \implies \exists n : x \in A_n$. For the lower bound, fix a $\varepsilon > 0,$ and notice that for every $n, \exists x_n \in A_n : x_n \ge a_n - \varepsilon$ (why?). What does this say about $\sup A$?

We prove the following slightly stronger claim:

Proposition. Let $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an indexed family of subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha=\sup_{\alpha\in I}\sup A_\alpha.$$

We show the above by showing inequality in both directions.
Observe first that $M=\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$, being the supremum of $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$, is an upper bound for $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$. This means that $x\leq M$ for all $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$, so for all $\alpha \in I$, we have that $x\leq M$ for all $x\in A_\alpha$. Thus for all $\alpha \in I$, $M$ is an upper bound for $A_\alpha$, so $\sup A_\alpha\leq M$. But then as $\sup A_\alpha\leq M$ for all $\alpha\in I$, we have that $M$ is an upper bound for the set $\{\sup A_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$, from which it follows that
$$\sup_{\alpha\in I}\sup A_\alpha=\sup\{\sup A_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}\leq M=\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha.$$
We now show the other inequality. Observe that $m=\sup_{\alpha\in I}\sup A_\alpha$ is an upper bound for $\{\sup A_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$, so $\sup A_\alpha\leq m$ for all $\alpha\in I$. Consequently, for each $\alpha\in I$, we have that $x\leq\sup A_\alpha\leq m$ for all $x\in I$. Thus we have that $x\leq m$ for all $x\in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in I$, i.e. $x\leq m$ for all $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$. It follows that $m$ is an upper bound for $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$, from which it follows that
$$\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha\leq m=\sup_{\alpha\in I}\sup A_\alpha.$$
As we have shown inequality in both directions, it now follows that
$$\sup\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha=\sup_{\alpha\in I}\sup A_\alpha,$$
proving the proposition.

By taking index set $I=\mathbb{Z}^+=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, we get exactly your claim from the proposition.

$\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists a\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ so that $a>\sup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n-\varepsilon$. $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}^*$ so that $a\in A_{n_0}$ (or otherwise $a\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$), so $\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n\geqslant\sup A_{n_0}\geqslant a>\sup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n-\varepsilon$, $\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n\geqslant\sup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

$\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}^*$ so that $\sup A_{n_0}>\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, so $\exists a\in A_{n_0}$ so that $a>\sup A_{n_0}-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n-\varepsilon$, $\sup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\geqslant a>\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n-\varepsilon$, $\sup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\geqslant\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n$.

So we have $\sup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\sup_{n\geqslant1}\sup A_n$.
